What would happen if I connect a AC input to a DC-DC flyback converter without any rectifier?
I have a DC-DC flyback which has a 47uF, 450V bypass capacitor at the input. What would happen if I connect a 220 V AC supply at the input instead of DC? Will the bypass capacitor blow off, or will I see some other effects on the flyback board?

I remember, back in high school electronics shop, they did a demo of connecting an electrolytic cap across an AC power cord and plugged it into 120 v AC. It was quite a fireworks show.


What would happen if I connect a AC input to a DC-DC flyback converter without any rectifier?

It will almost certainly destroy the converter. My guess is that the first thing to go would be the controller chip. However, if you have a polarized (i.e. electrolytic) input capacitor, that is likely to go as well, possibly explosively.
